# vb.net datagridview filtering colum not running

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Recently I developed a pos but the data search is giving errors. Here is some code:

```
 Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
    DV.RowFilter = String.Format("[barkod] Like '%" & TextBoxPrebBarkod.Text & "%'")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
```

at the top i declared:

```
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    konekcija = New MySqlConnection
    konekcija.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=baza"
```

Here is the rest of my code:

```
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter

    Dim bSource As New BindingSource

    Try
        konekcija.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select barkod as 'Баркод', naziv as 'Назив', kupovna as 
'Куповна', prodazna as 'Продажна', opis as 'Опис', profit as 'Профит', 
proizvoditel as 'Производител', ddv as 'ДДВ', kolicina as 'Количина' 
, makpr as 'Македонски производ' from baza.artikli"
                    comm = New MySqlCommand(Query, konekcija)
                    SDA.SelectCommand = comm
                    SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
                    bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
                    SDA.Update(dbDataSet)
                    konekcija.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
```

Comment: check the code i updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to filter a query result, but `is giving errors` is not very helpful as to what the problem is.

First, when you Alias a column (`barkod as 'Баркод'`) the Alias names **are** added to the `DataTable` as that name; there would be no point to an Alias (`As Foo`) it if it didn't use them.  If `AutoGenerateColumns` is true for the `DataGridView`, those columns names will also be used for the `HeaderText`.

I am not sure why the OP code is using a `BindingSource`, the `DataTable` is really all you need, so I omitted it.

### Basic Query and Actors

```vb
Private dtSample As DataTable       ' form level object
...

Dim sql = "SELECT Name AS A, Fish AS Баркод, Bird As C, Color From Sample"

dtSample = New DataTable
Using dbcon As New MySqlConnection(MySQLConnStr)
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, dbcon)

        dbcon.Open()
        dtSample.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())

        ' prove that the DT column name is that of the SQL alias:
        Console.WriteLine(dtSample.Columns(1).ColumnName)   ' == "Баркод"
    End Using
End Using
```

1. This uses a form level `DataTable`.  Depending on what operations will be implemented, this prevents having to cast the DGV's `DataSource` in order to work with it elsewhere.
2. Note the use of `Using` to close and dispose of the DBConnection and DBCommand objects.  Under the hood, these allocate resources which need to be released.

### Explicit DataView

Depending on what the code does, a persistent `DataView` can be useful.  This will be used for the filtering:

```vb
Private dvSample As DataView         ' declared with dtSample
...
{query code from above}
dvSample = New DataView(dtSample)

dvSample.RowFilter = String.Format("Баркод LIKE '%{0}%'", "erm")
dgv2.DataSource = dvSample
```

I am not fond of using LIKE, but there you have it.

### Built-in DataView

That is slightly overkill because the `DataTable` has a built in `DataView` which this one will use:

```vb
dtSample.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("Баркод LIKE '%{0}%'", "erm")
dgv2.DataSource = dtSample
```

With either method, the results are the same:
[image]

You'd get the same results using the `BindingSource.Filter`.

[image]  The Alias columns from the SQL are used (`A`, `C`, `Баркод`)
[image]  Only rows containing "erm" for `Баркод` are shown

**Escape Illegal Characters**

Again, it is not clear what is to be fixed from *it gives errors* but possibly whatever is in `TextBoxPrebBarkod.Text` contains illegal characters.  Names like `O'Brian`, `Carol's Cookies` or `D'Angelo`  will cause problems because of the tick/apostrophe.  These can be escaped by replacing one tick with 2:

```vb
Dim filterText = "D'Artagnan"    ' e.g. user input like TextBoxPrebBarkod.Text
filterText = filterText.Replace("'", "''")     ' swap 2 ticks for 1
dtSample.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("Баркод LIKE '%{0}%'", filterText)
```

Of course, there is always the chance that whatever is in that TextBox doesnt exist in the `Баркод` column.

Answer (score 0):

the filtering colum not running because the filtered column `[barkod]` not exist in the datatable; you make in query `select barkod as 'Баркод'`.

if you want to show the header DatagridView with a specific name you can create query without (as) like this :

```
  Query = "select barkod, naziv, kupovna, prodazna, opis, profit, 
    proizvoditel, ddv, kolicina, makpr from baza.artikli"
```

and change name of header column in DataGridView like this :

```
DataGridView1.Columns["barkod"].HeaderText = "Баркод"
DataGridView1.Columns["naziv"].HeaderText = "Назив"
DataGridView1.Columns["kupovna"].HeaderText = "Куповна"
//...
```

And now you can apply your filter :

```
Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
DV.RowFilter = String.Format("[barkod] Like '%" & TextBoxPrebBarkod.Text & "%'")
DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
```