# Insert data to MySql and display in datagridveiw

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Recently i developed a pos but i have an problem inserting the data and displaying the names of the table in datagrid view 
here is some code :

```
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "insert into baza.artikli(barkod,naziv,kupovna,prodazna,kolicina,proizvoditel,opis) values ('" & TextBoxBarkod.Text & "','" & TextBoxNaziv.Text & "','" & kupovnacena & "','" & prodaznacena & "','" & kolicina & "','" & TextBoxProizvoditel.Text & "','" & TextBoxOpis.Text & "')"
    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, konekcija)
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader



    MessageBox.Show("Артиклот е успешно внесен !")
    TextBoxBarkod.Text = ""
    TextBoxKupovna.Text = ""
    TextBoxNaziv.Text = ""
    TextBoxOpis.Text = ""
    TextBoxProdazna.Text = ""
    TextBoxProizvoditel.Text = ""
    TextBoxKolicina.Text = ""
    konekcija.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    konekcija.Dispose()
```

And i tried:

```
Private Sub prikazitabela()

    konecija = New MySqlConnection
    konecija.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=bazaartikli123"
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim bazaDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim bajndsors As New BindingSource

    Try
        konecija.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select barkod as 'Баркод',naziv as 'Назив на артикал',kupovna as 'Куповна цена',prodazna as 'Продажна цена',opis as'Опис',ddv as 'ДДВ',makproizvod as 'Македонски прозивод' from bazaartikli123.artikli"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, konecija)
        SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
        SDA.Fill(bazaDataSet)
        bajndsors.DataSource = bazaDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bajndsors
        SDA.Update(bazaDataSet)
        konecija.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        konecija.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub`
```

Comment: Use SQL parameters always.  Why are you trying to execute a reader for an INSERT?

Comment: What is your actual problem and question?

Comment: After i insert the data i want to display it to the datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that can be improved, starting with using SQL parameters and executing your query:

```vb
Dim Query As String = <sql>
                         insert into baza.artikli 
                            (barkod,naziv,kupovna,prodazna,kolicina,proizvoditel,opis) 
                        values (@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7 )
                      </sql>.Value

Using dbcon As New MySqlConnection(MySQLConnStr)
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(Query, dbcon)

        ' I dont really know what datatype these really are
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxBarkod.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DTPNaziv.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Textkupovna.Text)
        ' ...
        dbcon.Open()
        ' this was missing: 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    dt = New DataTable
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM baza.artikli")

        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
        dgv2.DataSource = dt
    End Using
End Using
```

- I used an XML literal for the SQL mainly to avoid scrolling here, but it can make your code much more readable
- There is little context for the code in the question, but connections ought be created as needed; `DBCommand` objects are highly query specific, so they too ought be created as needed rather than using global ones.
- Use `Using` blocks to assure that `DbConnections` and other objects with a `Dispose()` method are properly disposed.  The code closes, but does not Dispose of the connection.
- Use SQL Parameters always.  These assure the **correct data type is passed**, avoid the cruft of `" Foo -'" & foovar & "' AND ..."` in code, **protect against special characters** in strings as well as prevent **SQL injection** attacks.
- Then `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` performs the insert.

After that, you can run a new query to get whatever data you want to display.  Note that you do not need to create a `DataAdapter` to fill a table.  It is not clear what you want to display, so that will also have to be modified for what you want.

When `AutoGenerateColumns` is True, they will be created when you set the datasource and the column names (== 'names of the table' ?) will automatically show.  If you want *different text* to display for the headers, you can either set them manually or uses aliases for them in your SQL, [as shown on a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37199888/1070452)

Comment: i updated the question i created a class that will display my data , btw thank you sir for answering my question you are great , can you tell me how to filter database by two arguments name and barcode

Comment: I am not sure where the class comes into play.  Filtering would just be a WHERE clause on the base SQL or a RowFilter on the `DefaultView`.  Those dont seem related to this question though